# Uploading video gets stuck between 40 - 45 % Gunicorn + Nginx + Django

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

Video is 385mb here is my nginx conf

```
server {
    listen 85;
    send_timeout 120;
    http2_max_field_size 64k;
    http2_max_header_size 64k;
    client_max_body_size 1000M;
    client_body_buffer_size 4096M;
    client_body_timeout 350;
    client_body_temp_path /home/mrlonely/lumendjango/media;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/mrlonely/lumendjango/staticfiles;
    }
    location /media {
        client_max_body_size 1000m;
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/mrlonely/lumendjango/media;
    }


    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/mrlonely/lumendjango/lumen.sock;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        #proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;
        proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;
        proxy_read_timeout 1200;
    }
}
```

It gives me : `net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`

Ive tried different things as you can see above, but i dont think the problem is with Nginx or Gunicorn, can't find anything good online. Can someone help me? If you need to see additional info please tell me, I dont know what else to put here.

Comment: Did you checked this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#std-setting-DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE ?

Comment: Yeah turns out  that the problem is with cloudflare, cloudflare limits post request to 100M, do you think i can solve this by uploading in chunks ?